# How to compare two sorted large lists efficiently in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have got two generic lists with 20,000 and 30,000 objects in each list.

```
class Employee
{
    string name;
    double salary;
}

List<Employee> newEmployeeList = List<Employee>() {....} // contains 20,000 objects
List<Employee> oldEmployeeList = List<Employee>() {....} // contains 30,000 objects
```

Lists can also be sorted by name if it improves the speed.

I want to compare these two lists to find out

1. employees whose name and salary matching
2. employees whose name is matching but not salary

What is the fastest way to compare such large data lists with above conditions?

Comment: You can use linq, it has a little performance cost but again as @Jon said is this enough for you or what else have you tried?

Comment: Where do you get your Data from? if you're filling your list from SQL, you might want to compare it directly from SQL and not from the lists.

Comment: Since they're sorted, a simple sequential traversal is O(n), is that too slow?

Comment: -1 too broad.  If the question were along the "I'm doing X in Y time; how can I improve?", I would not vote to close (assuming X & Y were provided).

Answer (score 2):

I would sort both `newEmployeeList` and `oldEmployeeList` lists by `name` - `O(n*log(n))`. And then you can use linear algorithm to search for matches. So the total would be `O(n+n*log(n))` if both lists are about the same size. This should be faster than `O(n^2)` "brute force" algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably recommend the two lists be stored in a `Dictionary<string, Employee>` based on the name to begin with, then you can iterate over the keys in one and lookup to see if they exist and the salaries match in the other.  This would also save the cost of sorting them later or putting them in a more efficient structure.

This is pretty much O(n) - linear to build both dictionaries, linear to go through the keys and lookup in the other.  Since O(n + m + n) reduces to O(n)

**But**, if you must use `List<T>` to hold the lists for other reasons, you could also use the `Join()` LINQ method, and build a new list with a `Match` field that tells you whether they were a match or mismatch...

```
        var results = newEmpList.Join(
            oldEmpList,
            n => n.Name,
            o => o.Name,
            (n, o) => new 
                { 
                    Name = n.Name, 
                    Salary = n.Salary, 
                    Match = o.Salary == n.Salary 
                });
```

You can then filter this with a `Where()` clause for `Match` or `!Match`.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: I assume (by the title of your question) that the 2 lists are already sorted.  Perhaps they're stored in a database with a clustered index or something.  This answer, therefore, relies on that assumption.

Here is an implementation that has `O(n)` complexity, and is also very fast, AND is pretty simple too.
I believe this is a variant of the [Merge Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm).

Here's the idea:

1. Start enumerating both lists
2. Compare the 2 current items.
3. If they match, add to your results.
   If the 1st item is "smaller", advance the 1st list.
   If the 2nd item is "smaller", advance the 2nd list.

Since both lists are known to be sorted, this will work very well.  This implementation assumes that `name` is unique in each list.

```
var comparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
var namesAndSalaries = new List<Tuple<Employee, Employee>>();
var namesOnly = new List<Tuple<Employee, Employee>>();

// Create 2 iterators; one for old, one for new:
using (IEnumerator<Employee> A = oldEmployeeList.GetEnumerator()) {
    using (IEnumerator<Employee> B = newEmployeeList.GetEnumerator()) {
        // Start enumerating both:
        if (A.MoveNext() && B.MoveNext()) {
            while (true) {
                int compared = comparer.Compare(A.Current.name, B.Current.name);
                if (compared == 0) {
                    // Names match
                    if (A.Current.salary == B.Current.salary) {
                        namesAndSalaries.Add(Tuple.Create(A.Current, B.Current));
                    } else {
                        namesOnly.Add(Tuple.Create(A.Current, B.Current));
                    }
                    if (!A.MoveNext() || !B.MoveNext()) break;
                } else if (compared == -1) {
                    // Keep searching A
                    if (!A.MoveNext()) break;
                } else {
                    // Keep searching B
                    if (!B.MoveNext()) break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't be both lists sorted before utilizing your algorithm? In this case you can't claim `O(n)` complexity. It is at least `O(n*ln(n)+n)` for eq. size lists

Comment: "How to compare two sorted large lists efficiently in C#?"  I was running under the assumption that the lists were, in fact, sorted.  However, his comment "Lists can also be sorted by name if it improves the speed" might indicate that the lists are not sorted, or it might indicate that the source of the lists can be pre-sorted (for example, a clustered index).  So I guess there's some ambiguity in the question.  I'll update my answer with a disclaimer.

Answer (score 1):

*One* of fastest possible solutions on **sorted** lists is use of [BinarySearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh.aspx) in order to find an item in another list.

But as mantioned others, you should measure it against *your* project requirements, as performance often tends to be a *subjective* thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Dictionary using

```
var lookupDictionary = list1.ToDictionary(x=>x.name);
```

That would give you close to O(1) lookup and a close to O(n) behavior if you're looking up values from a loop over the other list.

(I'm assuming here that ToDictionary is O(n) which would make sense with a straight forward implementation, but I have not tested this to be the case)

This would make for a very straight forward algorithm, and I'm thinking going below O(n) with two unsorted lists is pretty hard.

Comment: You have forgotten to add dictionary initialization complexity

Comment: Not sure where the log(n) would be coming from, as long as the hash buckets are plentiful, inserting a single item is pretty much a hash calculation and an insert at the calculated index.

Comment: Yup, this is why I **removed** `log(n)` from my comment